# how to get split months from two intervals?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've two dates in YYYYmm format

```
start : 202307
end : 202612
```

want to split them in interval wise, based on provided interval

for example split_months `('202307,'202405',5)`, will give me

```
((202307,202311), (202312,202404), (202405,202405))
```

tried with below code, bot stuck in the logic

```
def split_months(start, end, intv):
    from datetime import datetime
    periodList = []
    periodRangeSplitList = []

    start = datetime.strptime(start ,"%Y%m")
    end = datetime.strptime(end ,"%Y%m")
    mthDiff = relativedelta.relativedelta(end, start)

    if mthDiff == 0:
        periodRangeSplitList.append((start,start))
        return periodRangeSplitList

    diff = mthDiff / intv
    print(diff)

    for i in range(intv):
        periodList.append ((start + diff * i).strftime("%Y%m"))
    periodList.append(end.strftime("%Y%m"))
    print(periodList)
```

I tried, above code, but not working, can anyone share any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the logic here? Why would `'202307','202305'` give future years in result? Or is it a typo?

Comment: @alex, its type, its 202405

Comment: Your required output appears to be a tuple and yet your code is building a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a simple `while` loop?

```
def split_months(start, end, intv):
    from datetime import datetime
    from dateutil import relativedelta
    
    periodList = []

    start = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y%m')
    end = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y%m')
    step = relativedelta.relativedelta(months=intv-1)

    start_ = start
    while (end_:=start_+step) <= end:
        # add new period
        periodList.append((start_, end_))
        # update next start
        start_ = end_ + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
    
    # convert output to string 
    return [(s.strftime('%Y%m'), e.strftime('%Y%m'))
            for s, e in periodList]

split_months('202307', '202612', 5)
```

Output:

```
[('202307', '202311'),
 ('202312', '202404'),
 ('202405', '202409'),
 ('202410', '202502'),
 ('202503', '202507'),
 ('202508', '202512'),
 ('202601', '202605'),
 ('202606', '202610')]
```

If you want to add the last interval up to the end, change the `while` condition and add an extra line (`periodList.append((start_, end))`):

```
def split_months(start, end, intv):
    from datetime import datetime
    from dateutil import relativedelta
    
    periodList = []

    start = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y%m')
    end = datetime.strptime(end ,'%Y%m')
    step=relativedelta.relativedelta(months=intv-1)

    start_ = start
    while (end_:=start_+step) < end:
        periodList.append((start_, end_))
        start_ = end_ + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
    periodList.append((start_, end))
    
    return [(s.strftime('%Y%m'), e.strftime('%Y%m'))
            for s,e in periodList]
```

Example:

```
# split_months('202307', '202612', 5)
[('202307', '202311'),
 ('202312', '202404'),
 ('202405', '202409'),
 ('202410', '202502'),
 ('202503', '202507'),
 ('202508', '202512'),
 ('202601', '202605'),
 ('202606', '202610'),
 ('202611', '202612')]

# split_months('202307', '202610', 5)
[('202307', '202311'),
 ('202312', '202404'),
 ('202405', '202409'),
 ('202410', '202502'),
 ('202503', '202507'),
 ('202508', '202512'),
 ('202601', '202605'),
 ('202606', '202610')]

# split_months('202307','202405',5)
[('202307', '202311'),
 ('202312', '202404'),
 ('202405', '202405')]
```

Comment: Note that OP interprets the interval slightly differently: in their case, `5` means e.g. `('202307', '202311')` (i.e. 5 months: 07, 08, 09, 10, 11), while your solution includes one more month for each interval.

Comment: @mozway, not working for this use case ('202307,'202405',5), please check my question for expected output. If last two dates not having specified interval between them, should show whatever available

Comment: @Maria / simon you're right, my bad, see update. Can you provide the full expected output as the final interval in unclear

Comment: Now only the problem with the last interval is left: in the given example, it should end with `('202611, '202612')` (i.e. a shorter interval to cover the remaining months, including the special case of only one month left, which should be repeated)

Comment: @mozway, if after all splits, still some dates are left which are lesser than the interval, then just show that last interval as it is, irrespective of specified interval

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def split_months(start, end, intv):
    if start > end:
        raise ValueError("Start date is later than End date")
    intv -= 1 # to count start date as 1 of the intv months instead of start PLUS intv months
    periodList = []
    periodRangeSplitList = []

    start = datetime.strptime(start ,"%Y%m")
    end = datetime.strptime(end ,"%Y%m")
    
    next_date = start + relativedelta(months=+intv)
    while next_date < end:
        periodRangeSplitList.append((start.strftime("%Y%m"), next_date.strftime("%Y%m")))
        periodList.append(next_date.strftime("%Y%m"))
        start = next_date + relativedelta(months=+1)
        next_date = start + relativedelta(months=+intv)
    
    periodRangeSplitList.append((start.strftime("%Y%m"), end.strftime("%Y%m")))
    periodList.append(end.strftime("%Y%m"))
    
    return (periodRangeSplitList, periodList)
    

def main():
     periodRangeSplitList, periodList = split_months('202307','202612',5)
     
     print(periodRangeSplitList)
     print(periodList)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Simply get the start date and keep adding 5 motnhs until you go over the end date.

Outputs:

```
# split_months('202307','202612',5)
[
    ('202307', '202311'),
    ('202312', '202404'),
    ('202405', '202409'),
    ('202410', '202502'),
    ('202503', '202507'),
    ('202508', '202512'),
    ('202601', '202605'),
    ('202606', '202610'),
    ('202611', '202612')
]

# Interval smaller than available months
# split_months('202307','202309',5) 
[('202307', '202309')]

# SIngle month left
# split_months('202307','202405',5) 
[
    ('202307', '202311'),
    ('202312', '202404'),
    ('202405', '202405')
]

# start month later than end month
# split_months('202307','202306',5)
[('202307', '202306')]
```

I assume you'd want an empty list or an exception on the last case?

Comment: what if interval is larger than two dates ? can we just return (start, end), in that case

Comment: The output for `split_months('202307','202312',6)` is `[('202307', '202312')]`, you could return earlier but since you still have to do the last 2 appends to the lists I'd rather leave as is than duplicate those appends to the start of the function just for early return.

Comment: What should period list contain? all starts and ends except the very first start?

Comment: @Maria what should happen on the last case?

Comment: For now I added a ValueError raise, since the date format `YYYYmm` will always increase we can just do `start > end`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. The datetime and dateutil modules are the best tools in your box of tricks.

This code outputs a tuple as apparently required in the question:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

FMT = '%Y%m'
M1 = relativedelta(months=1)
P = datetime.strptime
F = datetime.strftime

def split_months(start: str, end: str, interval: int) -> tuple[tuple[int, int], ...]:
    start_dt = P(start, FMT)
    end_dt = P(end, FMT)
    result = ()
    rd = relativedelta(months=interval)
    while start_dt <= end_dt:
        s = F(start_dt, FMT)
        start_dt += rd
        e = end if start_dt > end_dt else F(start_dt - M1, FMT)
        result = *result, (s, e)
    return result

print(split_months('202307', '202405', 5))
```

**Output:**

```
(('202307', '202311'), ('202312', '202404'), ('202405', '202405'))
```