# Time span 6 months in python

Tags: python, html, time, range

I want to create a column of days-count like this

```
DATE            DAYS_COUNT
12/05/2022  0
15/10/2022  156
15/04/2023  338
15/10/2023  521
15/04/2024  704
15/10/2024  887
15/04/2025  1.069
15/10/2025  1.252
15/04/2026  1.434
15/10/2026  1.617
15/04/2027  1.799
15/10/2027  1.982
15/04/2028  2.165
15/10/2028  2.348
15/04/2029  2.530
15/10/2029  2.713
15/04/2030  2.895
15/10/2030  3.078
```

The input must be the ending date (maturity), the beginning (for example today or a custom date) and the span (in the example below 6-months starting from the end and moving backward).

I have tried to use `pd.date_range` but without success because i cant figure how to compute the difference in days with the starting point.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing some text on why it didn't work,, but also the code itself, a [mre]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. [Edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Use datetime's timedelta

Comment: I'm not sure if it's exactly the same case but [check this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77086913/5640517)